# laravel not working in nginx as alias

Tags: laravel, nginx, routes, config, alias

i have a nginx webserver and i want to run multiple laravel projects on it

first project is working fine but second project only opens home and home page address is

```
example.com/secondproject/
```

but when i want to open

```
example.com/secondproject/foo
```

nginx would skip /secondproject alias and looks for requested route in first project (root of server in nginx config)

this is my config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite_log on;

    location / {

        root /path/to/first-project/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        }

    }
    location /secondproject {

        alias /path/to/second-project/public;
        index index.php;

        location /secondproject {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        }

    }

}
```

and when i replace

```
root /path/to/second-project/public;
```

instead of

```
alias /path/to/second-project/public;
```

nginx shows 403!

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
   server {

        listen 80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {

            root /path/to/first-project/public;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php /index.php;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            }

        }

        # ------- second

        location /secondproject {

            root /path/to/second-project/public;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php /index.php;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: can't restart nginx after adding 

        location /secondproject {
            rewrite ^/* /secondproject last;
        }

Comment: just delete it, and try again